# Why doesn't this work? Is this a apscheduler bug?

Tags: python

When I run this it waits a minute then it prints 'Lights on'  then waits two minutes and prints 'Lights off'.  After that apscheduler seems to go nuts and quickly alternates between the two very fast.

Did i just stumble into a apscheduler bug or why does this happen?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import os, signal, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)   

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


def turn_on():
    #Turn ON
    print('##############################Lights on')


def turn_off():
    #Turn off
    print('#############################Lights off')


def schedule():
    print('Lights will turn on at'.format(lights_on_time))
if __name__ == '__main__':

    while True:
        lights_on_time = (str(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1)))  
        lights_off_time = (str(datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2)))  

        scheduler.add_job(turn_on, 'date', run_date=lights_on_time)
        scheduler.add_job(turn_off, 'date', run_date=lights_off_time)
        try:
            scheduler.start()
            signal.pause()
        except:
            pass

    print('Press Ctrl+{0} to exit'.format('Break' if os.name == 'nt' else 'C'))

    try:
        # This is here to simulate application activity (which keeps the main thread alive).
        while True:
            time.sleep(2)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        # Not strictly necessary if daemonic mode is enabled but should be done if possible
        scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the package, but since you schedule absolute time - no surprises here

Comment: I'm still having issues with this script.  It goes through one cycle then I keep getting missed trigger error messages.  Any ideas?  TIA

Answer (score 2):

You are flooding the scheduler with events. You are using the BackgroundScheduler, meaning that scheduler.start() is exiting and not waiting for the event to happen. The simplest fix may be to not use the BackgroundScheduler (use the BlockingScheduler), or put a sleep(180) on your loop.

Comment: I trtied using BlockingScheduler and sleep and I still can't get this to work.

Comment: @GabrielMoreno Can you provide more detail as to why it is not working?

Comment: @GabrielMoreno Have you tried using `job = scheduler.add_job(myfunc, 'interval', minutes=2)`. See the docs [here](http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/base.html#apscheduler.schedulers.base.BaseScheduler.add_job). You would only need to do this once and not need to use a while loop.

Comment: When i use Blocking scheduler instead of Background Scheduler on off message is only printed once each then it stops.  Sleep doesn't affect either one.

Comment: Interval wouldn't work for me since i plan to use this script to turn my lights on and off.  I plan to set up the script to turn my lights on an hour before sunset and off and hour after sunrise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


def turn_on():
    print('Turn on', datetime.now())


def turn_off():
    print('Turn off', datetime.now())


scheduler.start()


while True:
    scheduler.add_job(func=turn_on, trigger='date', next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=1))
    scheduler.add_job(func=turn_off, trigger='date', next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=2))
    time.sleep(180)
```

You should only start the scheduler once.